# Flink. Kafka Consumer does not get messages from Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am running Kafka and Flink as docker containers on my mac.

I have implemented Flink Job that should consume messages from a Kafka topic.
I run a python producer that sends messages to the topic.

The job starts with no issues but **zero** messages arrive.
I believe the messages are sent to the correct topic since I have python consumer that is able to consume messages.

**flink job (java):**

```
package com.p81.datapipeline.swg;

import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;


public class SWGEventJob {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SWGEventJob.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        final String inputTopic = parameterTool.get("kafka_input_topic","kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in");
        final String outputTopic = parameterTool.get("kafka_output_topic","kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out");
        final String consumerGroup = parameterTool.get("kafka_consumer_group","p81_swg_event_consumer_group");
        final String bootstrapServers = parameterTool.get("kafka_bootstrap_servers","broker:29092");
        LOG.info("inputTopic : " + inputTopic);
        LOG.info("outputTopic : " + outputTopic);
        LOG.info("consumerGroup : " + consumerGroup);
        LOG.info("bootstrapServers : " + bootstrapServers);
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<SWGEvent> swgEventConsumer = createSWGEventConsumer(inputTopic, bootstrapServers, consumerGroup);
        swgEventConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
        DataStream<SWGEvent> dataStream = env.addSource(swgEventConsumer).name(String.format("SWG Event Kafka Consumer [%s]",inputTopic));
        FlinkKafkaProducer<SWGEvent> swgEventProducer = createSWGEventProducer(outputTopic, bootstrapServers);
        dataStream.map(new SWGEventAnonymizer()).addSink(swgEventProducer).name(String.format("SWG Event Kafka Producer [%s]",outputTopic));
        env.execute("P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job");
    }

     static private FlinkKafkaConsumer<SWGEvent> createSWGEventConsumer(String topic, String kafkaAddress, String kafkaGroup) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
        properties.setProperty("group.id", kafkaGroup);
        return new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic, new SWGEventDeserializationSchema(), properties);
    }

     static private FlinkKafkaProducer<SWGEvent> createSWGEventProducer(String topic, String kafkaAddress) {
        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(kafkaAddress, topic, new SWGEventSerializationSchema());
    }

}
```

**Flink Job logs:**

```
2021-11-25 10:03:25,282 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils                          [] - Starting program (detached: true)
2021-11-25 10:03:25,284 INFO  com.p81.datapipeline.swg.SWGEventJob                         [] - inputTopic : kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in
2021-11-25 10:03:25,284 INFO  com.p81.datapipeline.swg.SWGEventJob                         [] - outputTopic : kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out
2021-11-25 10:03:25,284 INFO  com.p81.datapipeline.swg.SWGEventJob                         [] - consumerGroup : p81_swg_event_consumer_group
2021-11-25 10:03:25,284 INFO  com.p81.datapipeline.swg.SWGEventJob                         [] - bootstrapServers : broker:29092
2021-11-25 10:03:26,155 WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer [] - Property [transaction.timeout.ms] not specified. Setting it to 3600000 ms
2021-11-25 10:03:26,202 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.executors.EmbeddedExecutor [] - Job 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1 is submitted.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,202 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.executors.EmbeddedExecutor [] - Submitting Job with JobId=62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,301 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher     [] - Received JobGraph submission 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1 (P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,302 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher     [] - Submitting job 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1 (P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,306 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService             [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster at akka://flink/user/rpc/jobmanager_15 .
2021-11-25 10:03:26,307 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Initializing job P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,309 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Using restart back off time strategy NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy for P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,309 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Running initialization on master for job P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,309 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Successfully ran initialization on master in 0 ms.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,310 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.adapter.DefaultExecutionTopology [] - Built 1 pipelined regions in 0 ms
2021-11-25 10:03:26,310 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - No state backend has been configured, using default (HashMap) org.apache.flink.runtime.state.hashmap.HashMapStateBackend@252e8634
2021-11-25 10:03:26,310 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Checkpoint storage is set to 'jobmanager'
2021-11-25 10:03:26,310 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    [] - No checkpoint found during restore.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,310 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Using failover strategy org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.RestartPipelinedRegionFailoverStrategy@3931aba0 for P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1).
2021-11-25 10:03:26,311 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Starting execution of job P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1) under job master id 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,318 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Starting scheduling with scheduling strategy [org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.strategy.PipelinedRegionSchedulingStrategy]
2021-11-25 10:03:26,318 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job P81 Dummy SWG Event Flink Job (62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1) switched from state CREATED to RUNNING.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,319 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: SWG Event Kafka Consumer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in] -> Map -> Sink: SWG Event Kafka Producer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out] (1/1) (87c54365842acb250dc6984b1ca9b466) switched from CREATED to SCHEDULED.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,320 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Connecting to ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*(00000000000000000000000000000000)
2021-11-25 10:03:26,321 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Resolved ResourceManager address, beginning registration
2021-11-25 10:03:26,322 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registering job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_15 for job 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,324 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Registered job manager 00000000000000000000000000000000@akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/jobmanager_15 for job 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,327 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - JobManager successfully registered at ResourceManager, leader id: 00000000000000000000000000000000.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,328 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.DeclarativeSlotManager [] - Received resource requirements from job 62c766b4ace055cf91f97f1e46f621d1: [ResourceRequirement{resourceProfile=ResourceProfile{UNKNOWN}, numberOfRequiredSlots=1}]
2021-11-25 10:03:26,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: SWG Event Kafka Consumer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in] -> Map -> Sink: SWG Event Kafka Producer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out] (1/1) (87c54365842acb250dc6984b1ca9b466) switched from SCHEDULED to DEPLOYING.
2021-11-25 10:03:26,395 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Deploying Source: SWG Event Kafka Consumer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in] -> Map -> Sink: SWG Event Kafka Producer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out] (1/1) (attempt #0) with attempt id 87c54365842acb250dc6984b1ca9b466 to 172.18.0.4:35157-adeb80 @ kafka_taskmanager_1.kafka_default (dataPort=41077) with allocation id 968834ad9a512d16050107a088449490
2021-11-25 10:03:26,546 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: SWG Event Kafka Consumer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in] -> Map -> Sink: SWG Event Kafka Producer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out] (1/1) (87c54365842acb250dc6984b1ca9b466) switched from DEPLOYING to INITIALIZING.
2021-11-25 10:03:27,597 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Source: SWG Event Kafka Consumer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in] -> Map -> Sink: SWG Event Kafka Producer [kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_out] (1/1) (87c54365842acb250dc6984b1ca9b466) switched from INITIALIZING to RUNNING.
```

**producer job (python):** (Running on host machine - not docker)

```
import json
import os
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from random import randint

from kafka import KafkaProducer

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

_METHODS = ['GET'] * 17 + ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
_ACTIONS = ['ALLOW', 'WARNING', 'BLOCK']

_URLS = ['x']


@dataclass
class SWGEvent:
    url: str
    action: str
    agentId: int
    agentIP: str
    HTTPMethod: str
    timestamp: int


def _get_fake_swg_event() -> SWGEvent:
    url = _URLS[randint(0, len(_URLS) - 1)]
    action = _ACTIONS[randint(0, len(_ACTIONS) - 1)]
    agent_id = randint(1, 1000)
    agent_ip = f'{randint(1, 255)}.{randint(1, 255)}.{randint(1, 255)}.{randint(1, 255)}'
    http_method = _METHODS[randint(0, len(_METHODS) - 1)]
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    return SWGEvent(url, action, agent_id, agent_ip, http_method, timestamp)


def produce(producer: KafkaProducer, topic_name: str) -> None:
    x = 0
    while x < 500:
        event: SWGEvent = _get_fake_swg_event()
        result = producer.send(topic_name, asdict(event))
        x += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    producer.flush()
    logging.info(f'send result: {str(result)}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kafka_server = os.getenv('KAFKA_SERVER')
    topic_name = os.getenv('TOPIC_NAME')
    logging.info(f'Producer.Working with server {kafka_server} and topic {topic_name}')
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server, value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
    produce(producer, topic_name)
```

The python code print out:

```
INFO:root:Producer.Working with server localhost:9092 and topic kafka_fake_swg_event_topic_in
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8091

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8091

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.0.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8091'
      KAFKA_REST_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN: '*'
      KAFKA_REST_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD'
  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.13.2-scala_2.12
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.13.2-scala_2.12
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
```

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                   COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS          PORTS                                            NAMES
2f465a0a4129   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.0.0        "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours     0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp                           rest-proxy
eb25992c47d0   confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.0   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours     8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->8091/tcp                 schema-registry
1081319da296   confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.0             "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 hours ago   Up 17 hours     0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp   broker
de9056ee250c   flink:1.13.2-scala_2.12                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 hours ago   Up 28 minutes   6123/tcp, 8081/tcp                               kafka_taskmanager_1
b38beefc35e3   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0         "/etc/confluent/dock…"   23 hours ago   Up 23 hours     2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp       zookeeper
e6db23fa8842   flink:1.13.2-scala_2.12                 "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 hours ago   Up 18 hours     6123/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                 kafka_jobmanager_1
```

[image]

**Question**: what should be fixed in order to get messages into Flink job?

**Update #1**
Looks like the Job works.Events consumed by the Kafka consumer and produced by the Kafka producer. (I have learned that by looking at the Flink task manager log.) So the actual question is - **Why the Flink UI show zero activity?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flink metrics you are looking at only measure traffic happening within the Flink cluster itself (using Flink's serializers and network stack), and ignore the communication at the edges of the job graph (using the connectors' serializers and networking).

In other words, sources never report records coming in, and sinks never report records going out.

Furthermore, in your job all of the operators can be chained together, so Flink's network is not used at all.

Yes, this is confusing.

Comment: Got it.. Is there a way to tell (via GUI) how many events / bytes were handled by the job?

Comment: There is work planned to add these metrics for connectors using the new source and sink interfaces. See FLIP-33 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11576.

Comment: For now, if you force the source and sink to communicate across the network by using `env.disableOperatorChaining();` then you will see something (at the expense of slowing down the job). Or you could add a RichMapFunction between the source and sink that uses a custom metric to count the traffic flowing through it.