# Using Flink Table to consume Kafka messages but no output on console

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

The code is below. I want to get the sum of amount every 10 minutes.

```java
 StreamExecutionEnvironment env =  StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration());
        StreamTableEnvironment tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        String create_kafka_table = "create table orders(\n" +
                "    order_id string,\n" +
                "    order_item string,\n" +
                "    amount int,\n" +
                "    order_time timestamp(0),\n" +
                "    watermark for order_time as order_time - interval '1' minute\n" +
                ") with (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'kafka',\n" +
                "  'topic' = 'order_flow',\n" +
                "  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '127.0.0.1:9093',\n" +
                "  'properties.group.id' = 'order_consumer',\n" +
                "  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',\n" +
                "  'format' = 'csv'\n" +
                ")";

        tenv.executeSql(create_kafka_table);

        tenv.executeSql("select window_start, window_end, sum(amount)  " +
                " FROM TABLE(\n" +
                "    TUMBLE(TABLE orders, DESCRIPTOR(order_time), INTERVAL '10' MINUTES))\n" +
                "  GROUP BY window_start, window_end"
        ).print();
```

the data in Kafka like

```
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:35:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:38:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:40:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:50:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:52:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:55:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 10:55:00
1,a,10,2022-11-05 11:00:00
```

I noticed that the `GlobalWindowAggregate` task on webUI received records but did not send records. I thought the `window` worked but no console output really confused me.
[image]

Comment: Hopefully the answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70114144/2000823 -- will clarify what's going on.

Comment: Update: the issue is related to kafka source and parallelism. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096166/parallelism-in-flink-kafka-source-causes-nothing-to-execute/70101290#70101290